# Create circular grid line labels (labels around the map's border) for a South Polar Stereo projection

Tags: python, coordinate-system, labeling, cartopy, antarctica

I'm using the South Polar Stereographic projection to create a map of Antarctica. I've been able to create the gridlines using Cartopy, but the labels for the gridlines are not circular around the map, which is what I want. Is there a way to make the gridline labels follow the circular pattern of the South Polar Stereographic projection? Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as  mpath

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.SouthPolarStereo())
ax.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, -30], ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, color='darkgrey')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN, color='lightblue')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE, linewidth=1.25)

# Draw meridian lines with labels around circular boundary
ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True, linewidth=1, \
                xlocs=range(-180,171,10), ylocs=[], \
                color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--', zorder=10)
# Draw concentric circles (but hide labels) for the parallels of the latitude
ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=False, linewidth=1, \
                xlocs=[], ylocs=None, \
                color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--', zorder=10)

# Add circular boundary
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
center, radius = [0.5, 0.5], 0.5
verts = np.vstack([np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]).T
circle = mpath.Path(verts * radius + center)

ax.set_boundary(circle, transform=ax.transAxes)


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The output looks like

[image]

### What I am expecting:

[image]